# Is their any convention for measuring cooling in a material?

Tags: thermodynamics, laser, cooling

Im dealing with laser heating and cooling, in this area you have a lengths that are accepted measures such as an absorption depth and Diffusion length.

1. https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/pn-junctions/diffusion-length
2. https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/pn-junctions/absorption-depth

My question is if theres any accepted standards for cooling. For example, if i heat a material with a smooth pulse, it will heat up to a peak then decrease, is there such a measure like 20% of the max temp of a pulse is an 'cooling time'? Otherwise since the material can take such a long time to cool back to its original temp that to plot it all and to compare materials becomes difficult. It would be much convenient to be able to say in one cooling time the heat has flowed z distance etc.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are standards—characteristic times—for temperature changes. Broadly, because of [Newton's law of cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling), temperature differences tend to even out asymptotically. Analogous to the [half-life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life) of radioactive decay, for example, we tend to label times over which a fair fraction of the initial temperature difference has disappeared.

An example: if you blow cool air past a small, hot metal sphere, the sphere will [cool down approximately exponentially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped-element_model) with a time-dependent uniform temperature of

$$T(t)=T_\infty+(T_\mathrm{initial}-T_\infty)\exp(-t/t_\mathrm{char}),$$

where $T_\infty$ is the air temperature, $T_\mathrm{initial}$ is the initial sphere temperature, $t$ is time, and $t_\mathrm{char}$ is a type of *characteristic time* that you're asking about; at $t=t_\mathrm{char}$, the relative temperature difference  $\theta=\frac{T(t)-T_\infty}{T_\mathrm{initial}-T_\infty}$ has dropped to $\frac{1}{e}=37\%$ at the original value.

(The characteristic time here happens to be $t_\mathrm{char}=\frac{C}{hA}$, where $C$ is the heat capacity of the sphere, $h$ is the convective coefficient of the blowing air, and $A$ is the sphere surface area. Intuitively, a smaller $C$ and larger $h$ and $A$ result in faster cooling.)

For conductive heat transfer, a useful characteristic time is $\frac{L^2}{D}$, where $L$ is a characteristic length over which conduction is occurring and $D$ is the material [thermal diffusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_diffusivity). Within one or several of these characteristic times, conduction has nearly eliminated the initial temperature difference. The [Fourier number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_number), a very well-known nondimensional parameter in heat transfer analysis, captures this relationship.

Note that this $\frac{L^2}{D}$ characteristic time is obtained by a *scaling analysis*; it captures general trends but is not exact. As another example, for a heating pulse spreading out in a 1-D domain, Crank's *Mathematics of Diffusion* gives a solution of

$$T(x,t)-T_\infty\sim t^{-1/2}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4Dt}\right);$$

where we find a coefficient of $\frac{x^2}{4D}$ in the exponential term but also a $t^{-1/2}$ factor in front.

Other $t_\mathrm{char}$ parameters can be defined for different heat transfer mechanisms, such as radiation. It's a matter of solving the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) subject to the initial and boundary conditions and locating the exponential or exponential-like terms or sum of terms.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Have you got any suggestions for further reading on characteristic times?

Comment: Crank's *[Mathematics of Diffusion](http://www-eng.lbl.gov/~shuman/NEXT/MATERIALS&COMPONENTS/Xe_damage/Crank-The-Mathematics-of-Diffusion.pdf)* (especially Section 8.2), Incropera & DeWitt's *[Fundamentals of Heat and Mass Transfer](https://hyominsite.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/fundamentals-of-heat-and-mass-transfer-6th-edition.pdf)* (Chapter 5, Transient Conduction), and [any heat transfer handbook that covers transient processes](http://160592857366.free.fr/joe/ebooks/Mechanical%20Engineering%20Books%20Collection/HEAT%20TRANSFER/handbook%20of%20HeatTransfer.pdf) (here, Equation 3.72 on).